# Edge HTTPS Certificate Issue: ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED

Tags: internet, certificate, nginx, https, microsoft-edge

The title isn't great, but I don't know how to describe it. I recently installed new certificates for my Nginx server with certbot. If I access my website through (new) Edge, I get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfBaF.png)

However, if I run it through internet explorer or my phone, it works fine.

Is there some kind of cache to clear on my browser? If so, how would I go around doing it?

Comment: The error that is displaying is caused by a misconfigured certificate, expired, or corrupt certificate.  Chromium Edge and Internet Explorer have different rules when it comes to certificates.  What is deemed safe or acceptable to Internet Explorer will be evaluated by the same certificate rules as Chromium if your using Chromium Edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error NET::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED is related
to Chrome now requiring for some certificate authorities that the
SSL security certificates be registered into
[Certificate Transparency](https://www.certificate-transparency.org).

For checking Certificate Transparency, you may check that the certificate
has an *SCT List* field:

[image]

This is only required for Chrome at the moment. Other browsers don't require it
as yet.

If you bought the new certificate, demand that it be re-issued and registered
for Certificate Transparency.